# PHP / MySQL two rows in one array

Tags: php, mysql

Hy I have some problems with php and mysql -> I can't find a good solution for it.

This is my DB:

```
user_id | meta_key | meta_value
1       | name     | Freddy
1       | phone    | 123
1       | adress   | Elm Street 1428
1       | city     | Springwood
```

I'm getting datas this way:

```
$userdata = array (userdata);
$get_user_data = mysql_query("SELECT `meta_value` FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id", $link);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_user_data)){
array_push($userdata, $row["meta_value"]);}
```

What i don't like is:
I can only get data this way -> `$userdata[1];`

How can i get my data that there is a connection between the two rows?

`$userdata['name'];` (Freddy)

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: how would this code look like if i use mysqli?

Can i just use
mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_array insted of?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the meta_key as index in your array, just add the data like this:

```
// add meta_key to the query
$get_user_data = mysql_query("SELECT `meta_value`,`meta_key` FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id", $link);

// use _assoc instead of _array, we don't need the numerical indexes.
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_data)){
  $userdata[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

This will result in:

```
Array(
  'name' => 'Freddy',
  // ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_user_data, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ....
}
```

or:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_data)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is unnessecary, `mysql_fetch_array()` returns by default an array with numerical and associative indexes.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Indeed, but by using an associative array the numeric values are left out.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_fetch_array($get_user_data, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

Comment: this is unnessecary, `mysql_fetch_array()` returns by default an array with numerical and associative indexes.